# Spring Framework Bean refers to a singleton instance defined in Java code

Tags: spring, frameworks, javabeans

I am new to Spring Framework. I come across a situation where our bean definition needs to refer to an existing singleton already defined in Java code.

A bit more details, a singleton (sFoo) of a class Foo is defined in a 3rd party jar file. And Foo has not factory API. Plus Foo prohibits creating a instance with the same parameter as sFoo. So there seems to be no way to declare a bean ( with singleton scope) due to the lack of factory API from Foo class

I need to refer to sFoo from the definition of other beans.

Is there any way to refer to sFoo from bean's definition xml file ?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Create a Bean of Foo in your configuration class and refer that Bean only

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClass {
   @Bean
   public  Foo foo(){
        //This will ensure one object of Foo is created
        return new Foo();
   }
}

@Component or @Service or any Spring stereotype annotation
public OtherClass{

  @Autowired
  Foo foo; //This is the Singleton instance created in ConfigClass
}
```